# Literate Agda: How do I change the size of the displayed code?

Tags: agda, latex

I am making Beamer slides for a talk about an Agda formalisation of mine.

In order to make the code fit onto the slide, I need to scale the font size. One would think that this might not be so hard, but the previous 20 tricks that I've tried all fail in the sense that, post compilation with `agda --latex`, the relevant tricks simply disappear from the output file.

I tried setting the global document font size to the smallest possible option (and then using `\Huge` for all remaining text), but `8pt` on a Beamer project is still quite large and doesn't quite give me the room that I need.

Has anybody here ever been able to successfully change the code output size in a Literate Agda project?

*P.S. There exists at least one absolutely unpalatable solution: hand modifying the output latex files.*

Comment: As it would happen, in the weirdest twist, it turns out that the modifiers `\tiny` and `\scriptsize` **do** affect Agda code while the modifier `\small` does not (this was what I first attempted)! I would still like for a solution that lets me scale by any numeric factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a LaTeX question. All the generated code will typically end up in a `code` environment and so you can use a LaTeX solution to patch that environment.

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123530/26482), I get the following file:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{agda}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\code}{\fontsize{15}{18}}\selectfont
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is not in a code environment

\begin{code}
module LaTeX where
-- this is in a code environment
\end{code}

And we're back out of the code environment

\end{document}
```

and this is what the output looks like:

[image: Result once compiled]

The first argument to fontsize is the actual size, the second is the distance between the bottom of 2 consecutive lines in a paragraph so should probably be ~20% bigger than the first one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The issue that I'm experiencing with this now is that adding your three lines makes the `\begin{code}[hide]` optioned variant stop working.

Comment: However using `\AtBeginEnvironment{code}{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont}` does work!